# DbDataSourceEnumerator returns empty table with OracleDatabaseClient

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2013

This C# code used to work with VS 2010, to find the Oracle databases that are available via TNS:

```
string ProviderName = "Oracle.DataAccess.Client";
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ProviderName);
if (factory.CanCreateDataSourceEnumerator)
    {
         DbDataSourceEnumerator dsenum = factory.CreateDataSourceEnumerator();
         DataTable dt = dsenum.GetDataSources();
         .....
    }
```

After replacing VS2010 by VS Express 2013, no errors occurs, but the table `dt` is always empty, no rows. Anybody any idea what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. If there is a syntax error in the TNSNAMES.ORA, an empty table is returned. You don't get the correct entries from the file as you could expect. One mistake ruines them all.